# construction of four dimensional regular convex polytopes

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes

Could anybody give me a reference book about the explicit construction of the 6 regular four dimensional convex polytopes. I cannot easily find Schläfli's original paper so I am looking for a modern reference. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Coxeter's *Regular Polytopes* might serve: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Polytopes_(book)).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_regular_polychoron